# How to disable 'Path prefix language code' for admin panel?

Tags: i18n-l10n

My sites requires the use of 'Path prefix language code' under `admin/config/regional/language/edit/en` to append the language prefix to the URL path, so if the language is English, `node/1` would become `en/node/1`

The problem is that when I am trying to translate content, the links to the translation pages contain this prefix too, and that will reach a page that is not there:

**`/tc`**`/my-node-title/edit/zh-hant` is the wrong path, the correct path is...

`/my-node-title/edit/zh-hant`

So is there a way to remove the language prefix on the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the [GlobalRedirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module? You may be able to set the option 'Language Path Checking' to true in the module configuration page and add the paths for admin pages in there.